# Na linguagem C, não consigo trabalhar adequadamente com uma matriz

Tags: c

Olá. Em um projeto de faculdade para automatizar o processo de criptografia de ponta a ponta, encontrei alguns problemas ao lidar com matrizes.
OBS: Desculpe pelos erros de formatação do código. Ainda não peguei o jeito.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()

{
    //Variaveis
    long int tamanhoM1=0, //Variavel de controle do tamanho da 'matriz1'
        linha=0,          //Variavel para percorrer a 'matriz1'
        coluna=0,         //Variavel para percorrer a 'matriz1'
        x=0,              //Variavel para pecorrer o vetor 'fraseOriginal'
        matrizCodificada[tamanhoM1][tamanhoM1]; //Onde iremos codificar em ASCII nossa 'matriz1'
unsigned char fraseOriginal[x],
    matriz1[tamanhoM1][tamanhoM1];


   //Codigo
    printf("Digite o tamanho da matriz COM LETRAS E ESPAÇOS\n");
    printf("Na duvida,ponha um tamanho maior que será completado com espaços\n");
    scanf("%i",&tamanhoM1);

    printf("Digite a sua frase:\n");
   while ( x != pow(tamanhoM1,2)) //O laço vai ler do teclado um caractere até que encontre o quadrado do 'tamanhoM1'
{                             //Pois uma matriz 2x2 cabe 2^2=4 elementos
    fraseOriginal[x]=getche(); //Guarda na posição x um caractere
    x+=1;

}

x=0;  //Zera o X para percorrer o vetor do começo
printf("\n");

printf("Sua matriz é:\n");
   for (linha=0; linha < tamanhoM1; linha++)  //For aninhados para transformar o vetor 'fraseOriginal' em uma matriz 'matriz1'
{
    printf("\n");  //Quebra a linha
    for(coluna=0; coluna < tamanhoM1; coluna++)
    {
        matriz1[linha][coluna]= fraseOriginal[x];  //A matriz recebe o valor da posição do vetor de forma que percorre o vetor inteiramente

       x+=1;
       printf("%3c",matriz1[linha][coluna]);  //Impressao dentro do mesmo for pois quando se é feita fora do mesmo encontra-se erro


    }

}
printf("\nSua matriz codificada e:\n");

 for (linha=0; linha < tamanhoM1; linha++) //For para transformar a matriz de caractere para char(codigo ASCII)
{
    printf("\n");  //Teste de impressão
    for(coluna=0; coluna < tamanhoM1; coluna++)
    {
        matrizCodificada[linha][coluna]=matriz1[linha][coluna];
       printf("%5i",matrizCodificada[linha][coluna]);  //Impressão da matriz em codigo ASCII que encontra erro


    }

}


return 0;  //Fim
}
```

Ao rodar o programa, obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
Digite o tamanho da matriz COM LETRAS E ESPACOS
Na duvida,ponha um tamanho maior que serß completado com espaþos
2
Digite a sua frase:
ab c

Sua matriz Ú:

  a b
    c

Sua matriz codificada e:

   32    0
   32    0
```

O resultado encontrado na matriz final está errado, pois o esperado é:

```
97   98
32   99
```

O que pode estar acontecendo de errado?Estou manipulando a matriz erroneamente?
Grato desde já.

Comment: Uma dica: idente seu código previamente e para colocá-lo no editor de perguntas do SO simplesmente selecione todo o texto e aplique um tab nele antes de copiá-lo (na maioria dos editores atuais Ctrl+A seguido de Tab). Ao colar o código na sua pergunta ele já será identificado como um trecho de código e ficará com a mesma formatação original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não podes definir arrays com zero elementos; nem com valores constantes (em C89), nem com VLA (em C99).

```
char a1[0]; // declaracao C89 (C99, C11) invalida

int size = 0;
char a2[size]; // declaracao C99 (C11) invalida
```

Ve o [Standard C11 6.7.6.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2) (em inglês, a traducao é minha).

> > p1: [Para arrays fixos] Se a expressão é uma constante, tem de ter obrigatoriamente um valor superior a zero.
> >
> > p5: [Para VLAs] de cada vez que a expressão que define o tamanho do array é calculada tem de ter obrigatoriamente um valor superior a zero.